# dialogflow actions simulator not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying out dialogflow and Google actions.
Within dialogflow simulator, the tests work well, but as soon as I go to the actions simulator and do "talk to my test app", I keep getting:

```
My test app isn't responding right now. Try again soon
```

An trivia I created one day ago seems to work fine though.
Is there delays or bugs related to this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem which I fixed through the following steps:

- click on integration tab in dialogflow
- click on google assistant
- click on update draft
- click again on google assistant
- click on test
- click on view

If it still doesn't work, changing the language (twice) may work.

Comment: The UI changed just yesterday so it's a bit different now.
In any case, I tried to update draft, switch language, click out, reclick in, still no success :/.